# Cannot cmake box86 on arm cpu, unrecognized option '-marm'

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to install box86 with cmake in a script, the error I get in console is:

```
Scanning dependencies of target WRAPPERS
Scanning dependencies of target dynarec_arm
[  0%] Built target PRINTER
[  0%] Generating ../src/wrapped/generated/functions_list.txt
[  0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynablock.c.o
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynarec_arm.c.o
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-marm'; did you mean '-fasm'?
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynarec_arm.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-marm'; did you mean '-fasm'?
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynablock.c.o] Error 1
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynarec_arm_functions.c.o
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-marm'; did you mean '-fasm'?
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/build.make:89: CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/src/dynarec/dynarec_arm_functions.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/dynarec_arm.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Detected same build as last run, skipping
[  1%] Built target WRAPPERS
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

My script for this installation is:

```
git clone https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86

cd box86
echo 'cd box86'
mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. -DARM_DYNAREC=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo; make -j$(nproc)

exit
```

I'm not sure what this error means since I never specified -marm as an option... where is this coming from?

Comment: Very likely it's being set by something in the project's CMakeLists.txt.  Did you search for that option in the project?

Comment: The `-marm` is added because of `ARM_DYNAREC` option you have passed to cmake, see https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L182. This option is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/blob/master/docs/COMPILE.md). As far as I understand, this option works only on **ARM hosts**. But it seems you host is not ARM (e.g. it is x86).

Comment: @Tsyvarev `lscpu` shows aarch64 architecture, ARM vendor ID, 32-bit and 64-bit CPU op-modes, Little Endian...

Comment: CMake should print at the beginning of configuration which compiler it uses. Check that this is ARM compiler.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0` with python 3.7.3 interpreter